# Bootstrap - Tooltip is not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have created a [new website](http://fineconomy.gearnatic.com) (it is on a sub-domain atm). However, the tooltip on the text `Get the FinEco  Bookmarklet` is not shown.

```
<span class="bookmarklet"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> Get the
<br>
<a title="" data-original-title="" class="has-tooltip" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." href="javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://fineconomy.com/?link='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)); })();">FinEco  Bookmarklet</a>
</span>
```

Any recommendations why?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p8uzy3rp/

Answer (score 3):

We need to initialize tooltip inside `$(document).ready(){})` before using it.

Noticed that, from [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), they said:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.
>
> One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them
>   by their data-toggle attribute:
>
> ```
> $(function () {
>   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
> })
> ```

In your case, please add `jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` inside `ready()` function. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have this in your js file.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

check bootstrap website
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 2):

here is the code. hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="bookmarklet"><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> Get the
    <br>
    <a title="" data-original-title="" class="has-tooltip" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article." href="javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://fineconomy.com/?link='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)); })();">FinEco  Bookmarklet</a>
    </span>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I added the script but the tooltip does not get shown. I appreciate if you could have a look at my website again. http://fineconomy.gearnatic.com/

Comment: kindly try this <script>jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();</script>
hope it will work

Comment: Thx for your answer! I put it under the meta tags, but this also does not seem to work. Pls have a look at my webpage.

Comment: Sorry, chaning to `<script>jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();</script>` gives me the same result.

Comment: i checked your webpage. looks like you are using wordpress and jQuery is being used instead of $.
try replacing $ with jQuery. hope it will work.

Comment: you have put the script before jquery is loaded. try putting it inside the opening body tag and closing body tag. currently it is shown at line 14. and jquery is loaded at line 66.

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspecting your element in dev tools the title is empty on the element :

```
    <a href="/web/20151001210831/http://growthhackers.com/privacy_policy" 
data-original-title="" title=""><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> FinEco Bookmarklet</a>
```

Make sure to set the title and call the bootstrap `.tooltip()` function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a').tooltip()
});
```

***Update:***

It seems you have unset reference to jquery `$` variable, this means some code you are using have used `jQuery.noConflict()` so the global jquery object is now assigned to the `jQuery` variable and not the `$` variable.

So when you call your tooltop you shall use `jQuery` instead instead of `$`.

At the element level (the `a` tag)  you have not set the title attribute `title='your text'` in your `a` tag so the tooltip will not work, your tag shall be as below:

```
<a href="/web/20151001210831/http://growthhackers.com/privacy_policy" 
title="Drag this link to your bookmark bar. Click the bookmark when you want to submit an article."><span class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> FinEco Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: I added the script but the tooltip does not get shown. I appreciate if you could have a look at my website again. fineconomy.gearnatic.com

Comment: It seems you have unset reference to jquery `$` variable, use `jQuery` instead in when calling the tooltip function, you also have not set the title attribute in your `a` tag

Comment: Thx for your reply! Would you be so kind to update your answer so that I can better understand it.